# How to consumeTEIID Web service model operations using OData

Tags: odata, jboss-eap-6, teiid

I have a Web service model (with CRUD )deployed on JBoss EAP 6.1 which I can access using SOAPUI.

I have created a SOAP consumer model project using TEIID designer to consume the WS operations defined in the aboce WS model and I am trying to access it say  myhost:8080/odata/SOAPODataConsumer.1/BooksWebSvcView.GetBook?ISBNInput='99999999'

I get java.lang.AssertionError: org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.WrapperDataSource is was not a ConnectionFactory implementation

How can I consume WS model's CRUD operations on OData?

Answer (score 0):

See examples on consuming the soap web services here https://docs.jboss.org/author/display/teiidexamples/Examples

As per exposing the CRUD operations in ODATA, when you import the soap web service, Teiid gives ways to expose the operations as tables and stored procedures. Or you can design a stored procedure that can invoke a soap call. From here, Teiid exposes these as relational artifacts to anybody who is accessing them. Once the artifacts in that form, through ODATA it  should be a function call if invoking a stored procedure, or a POST method if it is going over a table/entity.